# Host domain on local Windows machine

Tags: dns, hosting, dynamic-dns, virtual-host

I just bought one domain, but my site is under development, so as of now, I don't want to buy hosting space.

For testing purposes, I've hosted my developed work on a local Windows machine (virtual directory). Now, I want to map it with my domain to show it to my client. Is that possible?

Comment: Possibly [This](http://www.thetechmentor.com/posts/how-to-host-a-web-site-from-your-computer/) could help you.

Comment: I'll give it a try, but my thought was like by just changing DNS entry with local IP and hosting our site on our local IP should work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to port forward the computer. When you did that you can give the IP (http://www.whatsmyip.org/) to him. In his browser he has to fill the IP in as url. For example: 
`145.75.244.23:7483`

Comment: What do you mean by `you need to port forward the computer.` could you please elaborate it more ?

Comment: He mean go to your router and forward the Traffic from a port. So the if you choose Port 7483 like in the suggested answer it will allow Traffic from the outside to access your site.

Comment: Yup.
On a Windows machine: http://portforward.com/networking/static-win7.htm
It's the same for Win 8 and 10